# Return match in a one-to-one table (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a df where I am sure the results are one-to-one like

| State | Abbr |
| --- | --- |
| Alaska | AK |
| Alabama | AL |
| Arkansas | AR |

How can I simply return one column given the other, as a string? So given 'Alaska', return 'AK'.

I tried

`df['abbr'].where(df['state'] == 'Alaska')`

But it just returns a Series. Do I need to just convert it to a dict or is there some simple solution I'm missing?

Comment: I think you are looking for `pd.Series.map` with `df.set_index('State')['Abbr']` as the arg.

Answer (score 0):

There many ways to achieve this:

```
result_1 = df.query("State.eq('Alaska')")["Abbr"].squeeze()

result_2 = df.set_index("State").at["Alaska", "Abbr"]

result_3 = df[df["State"] == "Alaska"]["Abbr"].squeeze()
```